# Where does Java save proxy details?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, java

My question is as the title states really. But to give a bit more detail as to what I would like to know, basically we have a small group of users who wish to create small video tutorials to distribute on the net. They've found a website which provides this functionality for free and it makes use of Java. The issue is that as default Java picks up its proxy settings automatically from IE and it doesn't seem to be doing this (our IE is set with automatically detect settings). The way around this is to manually enter our proxy address into Javas settings, however users do not have access to do this.

So where does Java save its proxy settings when they are manually entered into Java? Once I know that then I can change the appropriate registry/ini settings.

So if anyone could provide help it would be appreciated.

(P.S wasn't 100% sure if this should have gone on server fault or Super user so let me know if this is the wrong site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the resolution to this, Java keeps a file called deployment.properties in application data (drive:\application data\Sun\Java\Deployment), this file contains the data that points to a proxy if it has been set, so I simply copied a modified one into the users application data folder and now java runs correctly on the releant sites.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through the command line via the following arguments to the java command for per instance cases.

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

You may also create or edit a file called `net.properties` within your `$JAVA_HOME/lib` folder containing the following properties

```
java.net.useSystemProxies=false
http.proxyHost=hostname
http.proxyPort=80
https.proxyHost=hostname
https.proxyPort=443
#... etc.
```

Refer to the following for a list of available network properties that may be configured [Java6 Networking Properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html)

Comment: `$JAVA_HOME/lib` doesn't make sense for Windows Users. I do like the command-line example however.